# How to print a Vec?

Tags: rust, println

I tried the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let v2 = vec![1; 10];
    println!("{}", v2);
}
```

But the compiler complains:

```
error[E0277]: `std::vec::Vec<{integer}>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
 --> src/main.rs:3:20
  |
3 |     println!("{}", v2);
  |                    ^^ `std::vec::Vec<{integer}>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
  |
  = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<{integer}>`
  = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

Does anyone implement this trait for `Vec<T>`?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

```
let v2 = vec![1; 10];
println!("{:?}", v2);
```

`{}` is for strings and other values which can be displayed directly to the user. There's no single way to show a vector to a user.

The `{:?}` formatter can be used to debug it, and it will look like:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

`Display` is the trait that provides the method behind `{}`, and `Debug` is for `{:?}`

Comment: This is the correct answer for the title of the question. Also works with arrays, not only `vec!`

Comment: Is there a way to format a vector more beautifully, so it's not just a one-line print?

Comment: @Anatoly you can use the alternative specifier `{:#?}` to make the output spread multiple lines

Comment: While this is a concise answer to the question, it could be improved by explaining (or linking to an explanation of) **why** `Display` is not already implemented for `Vec<T>`. The sentence _"There's no single way to show a vector to a user."_ is not an explanation. For anyone else that is curious as I was, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33759549/19770795) explains it nicely and links the relevant [RFC](https://github.com/aturon/rfcs/blob/show-string-guidelines/text/0000-show-string-guidelines.md) underpinning the decision not to implement `Display` for things like `Vec<T>`.

Answer (score 74):

> Does anyone implement this trait for `Vec<T>` ?

No.

And surprisingly, this is a demonstrably correct answer; which is rare since proving the absence of things is usually hard or impossible. So how can we be so certain?

Rust has very strict coherence rules, the `impl Trait for Struct` can only be done:

- either in the same crate as `Trait`
- or in the same crate as `Struct`

and nowhere else; let's [try it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6bd36ab0fcaafb97174c&version=stable):

```
impl<T> std::fmt::Display for Vec<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, _: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

yields:

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<T>`)
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | impl<T> std::fmt::Display for Vec<T> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
  |
  = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

Furthermore, to use a trait, it needs to be in scope (and therefore, you need to be linked to its crate), which means that:

- you are linked both with the crate of `Display` and the crate of `Vec`
- neither implement `Display` for `Vec`

and therefore leads us to conclude that no one implements `Display` for `Vec`.

---

As a work around, as indicated by Manishearth, you can use the `Debug` trait, which is invokable via `"{:?}"` as a format specifier.

Comment: Does the error E0210 mean that it is only allowed to implement trait Display in the file collections/vec.rs ?

Comment: @highfly22: my understanding is that it should be in same crate, not necessarily the same file.

Comment: What? So I cannot ad-hoc add a Display trait impl in the module where I need it for a type in another crate?

Comment: @BitTickler: No. The solution is to declare a new type: `struct Mine(That3rdPartyType);` and then `impl Display for Mine`.

Comment: Here is a "newtype" example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b28b96a28d081601e2e09b1fc26f8ade&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Comment: Wonderful explanation!

Answer (score 26):

If you know the type of the elements that the vector contains, you could make a struct that takes vector as an argument and implement `Display` for that struct.

```
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter, Error};

struct NumVec(Vec<u32>);

impl Display for NumVec {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let mut comma_separated = String::new();

        for num in &self.0[0..self.0.len() - 1] {
            comma_separated.push_str(&num.to_string());
            comma_separated.push_str(", ");
        }

        comma_separated.push_str(&self.0[self.0.len() - 1].to_string());
        write!(f, "{}", comma_separated)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let numbers = NumVec(vec![1; 10]);
    println!("{}", numbers);
}
```

Comment: There's no requirement that you must know the *exact* type of the elements; you can [use a generic and allow any type that implements `Display`](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=38a0d87690419c4c1e7280c95e155d0b&version=stable).

Comment: Unfortunately shepmasters gist isn't working anymore. I've rebuild one from the examples here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b28b96a28d081601e2e09b1fc26f8ade&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Answer (score 14):

Here is a one-liner which should also work for you:

`println!("[{}]", v2.iter().fold(String::new(), |acc, &num| acc + &num.to_string() + ", "));`

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6faf681b6de0705dc0fed980753a7a90&version=stable&backtrace=0) is 
a runnable example.

---

In my own case, I was receiving a `Vec<&str>` from a function call.  I did not want to change the function signature to a custom type (for which I could implement the `Display` trait).

For my one-of case, I was able to turn the display of my `Vec` into a one-liner which I used with `println!()` directly as follows:

```
println!("{}", myStrVec.iter().fold(String::new(), |acc, &arg| acc + arg));
```

(The lambda can be adapted for use with different data types, or for more concise `Display` trait implementations.)

Answer (score 9):

Starting with Rust 1.58, there is a slightly more concise way to print a vector (or any other variable).  This lets you put the variable you want to print inside the curly braces, instead of needing to put it at the end.  For the debug formatting needed to print a vector, you add `:?` in the braces, like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v2 = vec![1; 10];
    println!("{v2:?}");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes you don't want to use something like the accepted answer

```
let v2 = vec![1; 10];
println!("{:?}", v2);
```

because you want each element to be displayed using its `Display` trait, not its `Debug` trait; however, as noted, you can't implement `Display` on `Vec` because of Rust's coherence rules. Instead of implementing a wrapper struct with the `Display` trait, you can implement a more general solution with a function like this:

```
use std::fmt;

pub fn iterable_to_str<I, D>(iterable: I) -> String
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = D>,
    D: fmt::Display,
{
    let mut iterator = iterable.into_iter();

    let head = match iterator.next() {
        None => return String::from("[]"),
        Some(x) => format!("[{}", x),
    };
    let body = iterator.fold(head, |a, v| format!("{}, {}", a, v));
    format!("{}]", body)
}
```

which doesn't require wrapping your vector in a struct. As long as `it` implements `IntoIterator` and the element type implements `Display`, you can then call:

```
println!("{}", iterable_to_str(it));
```

Comment: This is a great answer. And I love how people instead suggest to use the debug printing instead of saying you can't do that.

Comment: It is definitely should be the default answer.

Comment: This answer is bad because the fold is O(n^2) because it copies the string in every step.

Answer (score -1):

Is there any reason not to write the vector's content item by item w/o former collecting? *)

```rust
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter, Error};

struct NumVec(Vec<u32>);

impl Display for NumVec {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let v = &self.0;
        if v.len() == 0 {
            return Ok(());
        }
        for num in &v[0..v.len() - 1] {
            if let Err(e) = write!(f, "{}, ", &num.to_string()) {
                return Err(e);
            }
        }
        write!(f, "{}", &v[v.len() - 1])
    }
}

fn main() {
    let numbers = NumVec(vec![1; 10]);
    println!("{}", numbers);
}
```

*) No there isn't.

Because we want to display something, the `Display` trait is implemented for sure. So this is correct Rust because: the Doc says about the [ToString trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html):

"This trait is automatically implemented for any type which implements the `Display` trait. As such, `ToString` shouldn’t be implemented directly: `Display` should be implemented instead, and you get the `ToString` implementation for free."

In particular on microcontrollers where space is limited I definitely would go with this solution and write immediately.