# Mismatched types when displaying a matrix with a for loop

Tags: rust, display

Inspired by the code provided by evilone in the post [How to print a Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320083/how-to-print-a-vec). To display a matrix, I wrote code as following:

```
use std::{ops, fmt};

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Matrix<T> {
    data: Vec<T>,
    row: usize,
    col: usize,
}

impl<T: Copy> Matrix<T> {       
    pub fn new(row: usize, col: usize, values: &[T]) -> Matrix<T> {
        Matrix {
            data: values.to_vec(), 
            row: row,
            col: col,
        }
    }
}    

//// Display
impl<T: fmt::Display> fmt::Display for Matrix<T> {

    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        let n_row = self.row;
        let n_col = self.col;
        let data = self.data;

        for i in 0.. n_row {
            let mut each_row = String::new(); 

            for j in 0.. n_col {
                let idx = i * n_col + j;  
                let each_element = data[idx];
                each_row.push_str(&each_element.to_string());
                each_row.push_str(" ");  // seperated by space 
            }
            write!(f, "{}", each_row)   
        }
    }
}    

fn main() {
    let x = Matrix::new(2, 3, &[-6, -5, 0, 1, 2, 3]);
    println!("{}", x);

}
```

I got the errors:

```
rustc 1.13.0 (2c6933acc 2016-11-07)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> <anon>:40:13
   |
40 |             write!(f, "{}", each_row)   
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found enum `std::result::Result`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
   = note:    found type `std::result::Result<(), std::fmt::Error>`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> <anon>:31:9
   |
31 |         for i in 0.. n_row {
   |         ^ expected enum `std::result::Result`, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `std::result::Result<(), std::fmt::Error>`
   = note:    found type `()`
```

1) I don't understand why I get `` expected (), found enum `std::result::Result` ``

2) For the second error, I thought it was caused by the failure to implement line 40. So if fix line 40, it won't be a problem anymore.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this problem:

```rust
fn foo() -> u8 {
    for i in 0..1u8 {
        i
    }
}
```

It produces these familiar errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:3:9
  |
3 |         i
  |         ^ expected `()`, found `u8`
  |
help: you might have meant to return this value
  |
3 |         return i;
  |         ++++++  +

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:2:5
  |
1 |   fn foo() -> u8 {
  |               -- expected `u8` because of return type
2 | /     for i in 0..1u8 {
3 | |         i
4 | |     }
  | |_____^ expected `u8`, found `()`
```

Now the question is "what type and value does a `for` loop evaluate to?" (Hint: the compiler messages actually tell you if you read them the right way)

We *know* that the function must return a `u8`, but the compiler tells us that we are actually returning a `()` — this is the second error. That means that a `for` loop evaluates to `()`! Since a `for` loop evaluates to `()`, what could possibly happen to the value that the `for` loop's block evaluates to? As you can guess, the answer is that the block *cannot* return a value!

Think about *this* example:

```
fn foo() -> u8 {
    for i in 0..0u8 {
        //
    }
}
```

What would *this* return? Probably nothing good.

---

Returning from our MRE back to the original problem, you need to explicitly return inner failures and explicitly return success after the end of the loop:

```rust
for /* ... */ {
    // ...

    write!(f, "{}", each_row)?;
}

Ok(())
```

This opens the door to other errors in the code, but I believe you are capable of figuring those out!

Comment: thanks so much for guiding me see the essence. I totally agree I should learn how to look deep in the error reports and make MCVE case. I am both struggling and learning a lot in Rust these days.

Comment: @enaJ keep up the hard work! Producing a reduced case that repeats an error is something that will help you throughout your programming career.

Comment: Definitely! I came from a python background, and started to learn Rust 6 weeks ago. They are quite different in many aspects. But I DO feel each language helps to see deeper/further of the other one.

Comment: I get `error: use of deprecated try macro`

Comment: @Danvil updated. Use `?` in modern Rust.