# What is the canonical way to implement methods on Vec<MyType>?

Tags: rust, vector

I have some struct `Animal`. I want to implement some methods on `Vec<Animal>`. I believe the correct way to do this is to create a new wrapper object called `Animals`. What is the correct object to make this wrapper though? A struct? An enum? Something else?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320083/how-to-print-a-vec) and its answer.  Not a duplicate question but it seems as if it's the answer to your question.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci that's actually the point of duplicates on Stack Overflow: do the *answers* of one question answer another question.

Comment: Thanks, @OnorioCatenacci. It looks like I do indeed need to wrap it in a simple struct, something like `pub struct Animals(Vec<Animal>)`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30325430/12663771) in particular was helpeful.

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't think that's the point of duplicates. Questions are only duplicates if they have the same set of _potential_ answers. Otherwise we can't add new answers to the closed question that are not an answer to the "duplicate".

Comment: @SvenMarnach fair enough clarification. The text shown is “this question already has answers here”. My point is that the questions don’t have to be exact duplicates, they just have to be solved by the same answers, which is what I think you are also saying.

Comment: @Shepmaster it looked a bit different to me. Thanks for the clarification!